# Selecting one UITableViewCell selects the other cells at that same position when you scroll up or down

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have a UITableView with Dynamic Prototypes.
I implemented the code below so that when I select a row, it will be marked and the previously selected row will be unmarked.
However, for example, the row I selected is displayed in the middle of the screen, then when I scroll up or down, another cell (which is in the same middle position of the screen) is marked.  In short, every view, there is a selected cell at the middle.
Please advise.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    return indexPath;
}
```

Comment: Show your code for cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are overwriting accessoryType in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method - this is called each time table is about to draw new rows which were invisible before (as you described when you scroll up / down).

You need to handle it also in that function and update accessoryType there - otherwise it will randomly reuse a cells with different accessoryTypes.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying just the visuals of cell, you're not updating the data model. Store the selected index path in a `@property` somewhere, and adjust `accessoryType` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.