# Selecting one UITableViewCell selects the other cell after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Even though it's common question but I'm not getting how to fix this.

I referred [Selecting one UITableViewCell selects the other cells at that same position when you scroll up or down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251986/selecting-one-uitableviewcell-selects-the-other-cells-at-that-same-position-when) But i didn't understand.

I'm having **allMumbaiArray** (using in cellForRowAtIndexPath) and tableview **alllMumbaiTableview**. By using following code i can select and deselect the row.

**UPDATED as per EI Captain's solution**

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrIndexpaths;
```

tableView Methods -:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

      if (cell == nil)
      {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
      }

      cell.textLabel.text = [allMumbaiArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([self.arrIndexpaths containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }


      return cell;

  }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    NSString *testing =[allMumbaiArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [self.arrIndexpaths addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    NSLog(@"%@",testing);
}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
     [self.arrIndexpaths removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

 }
```

**Issue :** 1) when i select first row after scrolling the tablewview another row get selected.How to Fix this?

2) After selecting and deselecting row continuously, how can i maintain the only selected row values ?

Comment: store indexpath of selcted cell and according to that fill tableview in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: is multiple selction enabled ?

Comment: @Misha yes but on scrolling (i followed  EL Captain's soln. but still its facing the issue - > i.e cell actually selected but UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark not showing. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution

make one mutable array that stores selected index of tableview cell..

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrIndexpaths;
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
if ([self.arrIndexpaths containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong: indexPath.row]])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {   

    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [self.arrIndexpaths addObject:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row]];

  }
```

**didDeselectRowAtIndexPath**

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [self.arrIndexpaths removeObject:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row]];

  }
```

Here is the sample project...

[demo project](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=09183378146877033023)

Comment: in   cellForRowAtIndexPath  after scrolling its entering into else{
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
so as a result again UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark vanished after scrolling.

Comment: NSIndexSet is simpler and more efficient than an array of NSNumbers

Comment: @EICaptain updated my question as per your solution.

Comment: @EICaptain ok waiting ... :)

Comment: @EICaptain but your answer is not working yet ? i'll check demo project :(

Comment: nope ! i followed each and every step from above soln. but after scrolling UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark not showing.

Answer (score 0):

If your cell are not showing accessory then you just need to reload them

```
[_ableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

try this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`.