# UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark get vanished after scrolling the tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on tableview multiple selection, deselect.

I'm having 3 table views (the tableview which have tag 400 i need multiple selection and 
deselection -> alllMumbaiTableview)

**My issue :**  When I'm selecting multiple rows, `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` get vanished
            after scrolling the tableview. But thing here i can see those cells are still in
            selected state only but not showing `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`.

[image]

**After scrolling my table is looking like this**

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrIndexpaths;
```

**UItableview Methods -**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

       static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


         if(tableView.tag == 100)
        {
              cell.textLabel.text = [typeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else if (tableView.tag == 300)
        {
              cell.textLabel.text = [specialityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else if (tableView.tag == 400)
        {
                if (cell == nil)
                {

                    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

                }
                if ([self.arrIndexpaths containsObject:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row]])
                {
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                }

                    cell.textLabel.text = [allMumbaiArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }
    return  cell;

 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {


        if(tableView.tag == 100)
        {
            _typeTextfield.text=[typeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            _typeTableview.hidden = YES;
        }
        else if (tableView.tag == 300)
        {
            _specialityTextield.text=[specialityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            _specialityTableview.hidden = YES;
        }
        else if (tableView.tag == 400)
        {

            UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            [self.arrIndexpaths addObject:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }

 }
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    if (tableView.tag == 400)
    {
        UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.arrIndexpaths removeObject:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row]];

    }

  }
```

**What i want :**

1) I want `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` even after scrolling the tableview (But should not get other rows selected when I'm selecting one. My previous problem -> [Selecting one UITableViewCell selects the other cell after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843412/selecting-one-uitableviewcell-selects-the-other-cell-after-scrolling) )

2) I need all only selected values into single array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use different identifier for each table & return cell for each tableview, then it worked for me

**Updated Code**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

      if(tableView.tag == 100)
    {

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem1";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }


       cell.textLabel.text = [typeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;

    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 300)
    {

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem2";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }


        cell.textLabel.text = [specialityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;


    }
    else
    {

            static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem3";

            UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {

                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

            }

            if ([self.arrIndexpaths containsObject:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row]])
            {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
            else
            {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }

            cell.textLabel.text = [allMumbaiArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            return cell;

        }



}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    if(tableView.tag == 100)
    {
    _typeTextfield.text=[typeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _typeTableview.hidden = YES;
    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 300)
    {
        _specialityTextield.text=[specialityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        _specialityTableview.hidden = YES;
    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 400)
    {


        UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        [self.arrIndexpaths addObject:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.tag == 400)
   {
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [self.arrIndexpaths removeObject:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row]];

   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest having each different cell identifier. I don't know how to set tableviews layout but it looks tableviewcell queue replaces other cells unlike you implemented above.

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

if(tableView.tag == 100)
{
    simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
}
else if (tableView.tag == 300)
{
    simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem1";
}
else if (tableView.tag == 400) {

    simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem2";
}

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```

Update final

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    NSArray *tmpArray;
}

@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1, *tableView2, *tableView3;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tmpArray = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tableView1];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tableView2];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tableView3];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    if (self.tableView1 == tableView)
    {
        simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    }
    else if (self.tableView2 == tableView)
    {
        simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem1";
    }
    else if (self.tableView3 == tableView) {

        simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem2";
    }


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    if (self.tableView1 == tableView)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"tableView1";
    }
    else if (self.tableView2 == tableView)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"tableView2";
    }
    else if (self.tableView3 == tableView) {

        if ([tmpArray objectAtIndex:0] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)indexPath.row] ||
            [tmpArray objectAtIndex:1] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)indexPath.row] ) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"tableView3";
    }

    return  cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 70;
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting .. can u please update your code with respect to my code?

Comment: Did you check that if ([self.arrIndexpaths containsObject:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row]]) case out well?

Comment: That'd really weird. Did you create tableview in storyboard? or programmatically

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your code, I tested it through creating single project but it works well as I expected. I will update code that I tested.

Comment: I have updated my answer :) finally resolved..thank u for ur support.. +1

Answer (score 0):

There are many to solve such issue .

But the simplest way is that do not reuse the cell in  `cellforrowatindexpath` .

create new instance of cell everytime & i hope your both issue solve .

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```

i hope it work for you , its works for me .

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the same thing by using button and changing its image on Selection/Deselection, below is the code that may help you.

cell.btnCheckMark.tag = indexPath.row;

```
    [cell.btnCheckMark addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc]init];
    str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cell.btnCheckMark.tag];


    //str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cell.lblText.text];

    if ([arrSelect containsObject:str1]) {
        cell.btnCheckMark.selected=YES;
        str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cell.lblText.text];
    }else{
        cell.btnCheckMark.selected=NO;
    }
```

-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

btn.selected=!btn.selected;

str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",btn.tag];
displayValues = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrName objectAtIndex:[str integerValue]]];

if (btn.selected) {
    [arrSelect addObject:[NSString stringWithString:str]];
   // NSLog(@"Name: %@",[arrName objectAtIndex:[str integerValue]]);
}
else{
    [arrSelect removeObject:[NSString stringWithString:str]];
   // NSLog(@"%@",[arrName objectAtIndex:[str integerValue]]);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

shrikant

i think this happening because of reusable cell.

you give try

replce

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```

with

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
```

> i think this will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am updating your code.

In ViewDidiLoad Method-

```
  if (self.arrIndexpaths) {
    self.arrIndexpaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

First Update cellForRowAtIndexPath Method:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];//Update


     if(tableView.tag == 100)
    {
          cell.textLabel.text = [typeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 300)
    {
          cell.textLabel.text = [specialityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 400)
    {
          /*  if (cell == nil)
            {

                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

            }*///Update
            if ([self.arrIndexpaths containsObject:indexPath])//Update
            {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
            else
            {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }

                cell.textLabel.text = [allMumbaiArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
return  cell;}
```

Second Update DidSelectRowIndexPath Method

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
if(tableView.tag == 100)
    {
        _typeTextfield.text=[typeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        _typeTableview.hidden = YES;
    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 300)
    {
        _specialityTextield.text=[specialityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        _specialityTableview.hidden = YES;
    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 400)
    {

        UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];//Update
           if ([self.arrIndexpaths containsObject:indexPath])//Update
          {
            tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
             [self.arrIndexpaths removeObject:indexPath];
          }
         else
          {
            tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            [self.arrIndexpaths addObject:indexPath];
          } 
         }
        }
```

Hope above code help for you.